# What is frag grenade in Gun Bros and how to use it?

Tags: android, gun-bros

While playing **Gun Bros (Brother in Arms)**, I see a Bro Op update saying

> "Kill 25 enemies using frag grenades without dying"

But I do not know where to get `frag grenade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the exclamation mark on your controls and select the frag grenades, it's probably the 4th one from the left.